# Sync Swing Timer to system clock

Tags: java, swing, timer

How to sync a `javax.swing.Timer`, that is called once a second, to the system (os) clock? Lets say it should be started at the beginning of the next second.

Comment: Just an idea: you could query the os timer and shift the delay at each call by the value needed to hit the next second?

Comment: Thats the question. The timer works with a fixed delay.

Comment: timer.restart() by test if is isRunning()

Comment: *"The timer works with a fixed delay."*  Yes, and that fixed delay might be 20 msec.  Checking the time 50 times per second you can keep the beat to the System time clock to within 20 msec.

Comment: It's not fixed, there's a setter for it! You can change it during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible option:

```
private void sync() throws Exception {
    int lastSecond = LocalTime.now().getSecond();
    do {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } while(LocalTime.now().getSecond() == lastSecond);
}
```